# With JavaScript + React, how to have a string evaluate inline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following works great in my function:

```
console.log(theme.colors.blues[1]);
```

I'm trying to make the last part dynamic like so:

```
const getColor = (theme, passedColorProp) => {
  console.log(theme.colors.[passedColorProp]);
};

getColor("blues[1]");
```

This is currently erring with:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (15:27)**

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, you access a property dynamically exactly how you've done it except you don't need the extra dot.

```
const getColor = (theme, passedColorProp) => {
  console.log(theme.colors[passedColorProp]);
};
```

Note that this works for a SINGLE property, but you can't nest it as you have in your example, for that you'll need to use two different variables:

```
const getColor = (theme, passedColorProp, id) => {
  console.log(theme.colors[passedColorProp][id]);
};

const theme = { colors: { blues: ['something', 'something else'] } };

getColor(theme, 'blues', 1); // 'something else'
```

Comment: is there a way I can still pass "blues[1]" and then use getColor to determine the two properties?

Comment: As Ori Drori says, you'll have to use regex or string split to extract the keys and loop over the properties one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex to extract the keys, then iterate them with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the values:

```js
const theme = {
  colors: {
    blues: ['blue0', 'blue1']
  }
};

const getColor = (theme, passedColorProp) => {
  const keys = passedColorProp.match(/[^\[\].]+/g); // match a sequence of everything but [ ] or .
  
  return keys.reduce((r, k) => r[k], theme);
};

console.log(getColor(theme, 'colors.blues[1]'));
```

Comment: Thanks but that is erring w `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Comment: That will happen if `theme.colors.blues` is returning `undefined`. As you can see it works in the snippet.